# Angular Model name appearing instead of value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a very weird problem that i have not seen before.

I have a simple ng repeat

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" data-aria-labelledby="customer-type">
       <li data-ng-repeat="customer in ctrl.customers">
        <a data-ng-click="ctrl.selectCustomerType('{{customer.Name}}', '{{customer.Id}}')">{{customer.Name}}</a>
       </li>
  </ul>
```

The markup renders just fine in browser  - like this

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" data-uib-dropdown-menu="" role="menu" data-aria-labelledby="customer-type">

      <!-- ngRepeat: customer in ctrl.customers -->

      <li data-ng-repeat="customer in ctrl.customers" class="ng-scope">
      <a data-ng-click="ctrl.selectCustomerType('Customer1', '1')" class="ng-binding">Customer1</a>
      </li>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: customer in ctrl.customers -->

     <li data-ng-repeat="customer in ctrl.customers" class="ng-scope">
     <a data-ng-click="ctrl.selectCustomerType('Customer2', '2')" class="ng-binding">Customer2</a>
     </li>
     <!-- end ngRepeat: customer in ctrl.customers -->

     <li data-ng-repeat="customer in ctrl.customers" class="ng-scope">
     <a data-ng-click="ctrl.selectCustomerType('Customer3', '3')" class="ng-binding">Customer3</a>
     </li>
     <!-- end ngRepeat: customer in ctrl.customers -->

</ul>
```

The problem starts after this. When I select the dropdown and select something, it calls the function **selectCustomerType**. 
Now when i debug this method, instead of returning values like customer1, 1 or customer 2, 2 it sends value as  '{{customer.Name}}' and '{{customer.Id}}' which is :

```
function selectCustomerType(name, id) {
console.log(name); // - this prints {{customer.Name}} instead of actual value
console.log (id);// - this prints {{customer.Id}} instead of actual value
//do something 
}}
```

I have used this at so many places, i am not able to figure why .. 
Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-click` expects an expression. You do not need the double curly braces.

Change this

```
<a data-ng-click="ctrl.selectCustomerType('{{customer.Name}}', '{{customer.Id}}')">{{customer.Name}}</a>
```

to be

```
<a data-ng-click="ctrl.selectCustomerType(customer.Name, customer.Id)">{{customer.Name}}</a>
```

Comment: Wow.. thank you.. its funny.. I actually tried this and the browser rendered it as  ~data-ng-click="ctrl.selectCustomerType(customer.Name,customer.Id)"~ for all the Li's. So i thought it must be a wrong markup